# Alphabetized LinkedList Sorting

Tags: java, sorting, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to self implement a sorting method to put the objects in a self-created Doubly Linked List in alphabetical order. I am however receiving a null pointer exception on the part that iterates through the letters in case the first few letters are equal. What am I doing wrong?

```
 for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
            for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
                for(int k = 0; k<current.getName().length() && k<next.getName().length(); k++) {
                    int char1 = (int) current.getName().charAt(k);
                    int char2 = (int) next.getName().charAt(k);
                    if(char2 > char1) {
                        temp = current;
                        current = next;
                        next = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                next = next.getRight();
            }
            current = current.getRight();
        }
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: In which line do you have NPE? And why do you check only "char2 > char1", but doesn't check "char2 < char1"?

Comment: The null pointer is in the for(int k...) line. But oh yeah that makes sense, I changed it. The exception is still present though.

Comment: Are you sure, that your algorithm is right? For example, what will happen if the lines have different lengths? Which one should be the first? And are you sure, that is right firstly change current and next (`if (char2 > char1) {...}`) and then call 'getRight()' from next and current, but they are already exchanged? I guess you should refactor your algorithm firstly